# Asc order mysql query taking time than Desc order

Tags: mysql, sorting, join, innodb, sqlperformance

i have query like this :

```
select 
   p.id, 
   p.status as status, 
   p.promotionid as id, 
   p.name as name, 
   p.promotion_type     as promotionType, 
   p.created_date as createdDate, 
   p.start_date as startDate, 
   p.end_date as endDate,
   p.orders_display_count, 
   p.users_display_count, 
   pd.display_name as displayName
from promotion p 
inner join promotion_details pd on p.promotion_details=pd.id 
where p.tenant_id = '1234' 
  and p.status = 'active' 
order by users_display_count asc limit 0, 40;
```

Above query is taking around 3sec but when i changed users_display_count to desc order it took 0.5sec.Both sorting order is using same 'users_display_count' column index,any idea why its happening like this and is there any way to improve asc order query?
Thanks.

Comment: [Edit] to show full table schema including column types and keys. Also, check and post execution plans.

Answer (score 0):

The effect that `limit` has on your execution time depends on your data content.

You are using an index on `users_display_count`. That means that MySQL will travel through your data in that order.

Let's assume that you have 40 active rows with `p.tenant_id = '1234'` and `users_display_count = 1000`, while all other tenants have some value `users_display_count < 1000`. In that case, when you use `asc`, the requested rows are at the very end of the index, so MySQL will have to read the complete index before it gets to 40 rows that fit. On the other hand, if you use `desc`, the first 40 rows read will fit, and you are done. This extreme case shows that it is not necessarily surprising if `asc` and `desc` have different execution time.

Your specific data will be somewhere in between. It also means, that a different tenant may be faster for `asc`.

How to make `asc` as fast as `desc`?

It depends a bit on why exactly the rows, when read `asc`, are less likely to fit the conditions. E.g. it could be that rows with larger value for `users_display_count` are more likely to have `promotion_details` (then `desc` is more likely to fit the `join`-condition). But assuming a relatively even distribution, most likely, adding a proper index should fix it. So try adding the index `promotion(tenant_id, users_display_count)` or (if a lot of rows are non-active) maybe `promotion(tenant_id, status, users_display_count)`. Then `asc` and `desc` will probably have more similar execution times (and most likely significantly faster execution times then now).